# Working with Execute SQL Task with ODBC source in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odbc, informix

I have created an Execute SQL Task in which SQL Source Type is variable. The variable created are below.

**startTime**: Provides current time

**endTime**: Provides end time

**startTimeFormat**: It is used to Format Date into required format to parse record

```
startTimeFormat = (DT_WSTR, 4)DATEPART( "yyyy", @[User::startTime]) +"-" +
RIGHT( "0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) MONTH(@[User::startTime]), 2) +"-" +
RIGHT( "0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) DAY(@[User::startTime]), 2) +" " +
(DT_WSTR, 2)DATEPART( "Hh", @[User::startTime] ) + ":" +
(DT_WSTR, 2)DATEPART( "mi", @[User::startTime] ) + ":" +
(DT_WSTR, 2)DATEPART( "ss", @[User::startTime] )
```

**endTimeFormat**: It is used to Format Date into required format to parse record

```
endTimeFormat: (DT_WSTR, 4)DATEPART( "yyyy", @[User::endTime] ) +"-" +
RIGHT( "0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) MONTH( @[User::endTime] ), 2) +"-" +
RIGHT( "0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) DAY(@[User::endTime] ), 2) +" " +
(DT_WSTR, 2)DATEPART( "Hh", @[User::endTime]) + ":" +
(DT_WSTR, 2)DATEPART( "mi", @[User::endTime]) + ":" +
(DT_WSTR, 2)DATEPART( "ss", @[User::endTime])
```

**callProcedureQuery**: This variable is used to build the Procedure call which includes startTimeFormat and endTimeFormat. And the variable is used in SQL Execute Task

```
"call sp_ccdr ('"+ @[User::startTimeFormat]  + "', " + "'" + @[User::endTimeFormat]  + 
"', '0',null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,'NULL','NULL','f'"+ ")"
```

In the **Execute SQL Task**, I am returning full set for which I have created a new variable **varExecTaskRslt** ﻿where Result Name is 0 and variable is of type **object**. This is how my Execute Task Looks.

[image]

**ResultSet:**

[image]

I am able to Parse this successfully, but when I execute the Execute SQL Task, I get an error. The error is below:

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "call sp_ccdr
>   ('2018-05-13 14:47:30', '2018-05-13 1..." failed with the  following
>   error: "Disconnected recordsets are not available from ODBC
>   connections.".  Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query,
>   "ResultSet" property not set correctly,  parameters not set correctly,
>   or connection not established correctly.

Please help me out with what the error could be.

Comment: If you're using SQL Server, why are you not using the OLE DB connection type? Also, I **assume** the datatype of `varExecTaskRslt` is object?

Comment: @larnu: Because my source is Informix and it uses ODBC connection. So cant use OLE DB. Yes Have mentioned that varExecTaskRslt is an object